# HTML input + formatting value to date

Tags: asp.net, html, css, formatting

I have date as a string `16/11/2010 12:00:00 AM` for example which I am inputting in

`<input type="text" value="<%: Object.Instance.SomeDateAsString %>" />`

Note: this can either be empty string or in `16/11/2010 12:00:00 AM` format only.

How can I display it it nicely to the user as a `16-Nov-2010`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="<%: Object.Instance.GetFormattedDateString() %>" />
```

then on your object:

```
public String GetFormattedDateString()
{
  String returnString = String.Empty;
  DateTime parsedDateTime;
  DateTime.TryParse(this.SomeDateAsString, parsedDateTime);

  if (parsedDateTime != DateTime.MinValue)
  {
    returnString = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", parsedDateTime);
  }

  return returnString;
}
```

Comment: hmmm :) - it is not SomeDate but SomeDateAsString. Thanks though!

Comment: Then I recommend creating a property on your object which attempts to parse the date string to a date object, then returns the formatted date if it succeeds, else String.Empty (if it fails).

Comment: +1 good idea. in your answer: does it still work if `SomeDate` is nullable? and is null? what do you see if it is null, if anything?

Comment: @VoodooChild - I think it will handle null values OK, but I'm not 100% sure - I always have to test the code to make sure, so I recommend you do the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) for many patterns of the DateTime.ToString() Patterns.
For your specific format you need: `DateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")`